# Read a txt file into a QStringList

Tags: c++, qt, qtcore, qfile

I have a file with 3000 strings (1 string-few words). I need to read the strings into a `QList`. How can I do that? I have tried the following:

```
1.txt
string
string2
```

function() <=> `MyList<<"string"<<"string2";`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### main.cpp

```
#include <QStringList>
#include <QFile>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QString fileName = "foo.txt"; // or "/absolute/path/to/your/file"
    QFile file(fileName);
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
        return 1;

    QStringList stringList;
    QTextStream textStream(&file);

    while (!textStream.atEnd())
        stringList << textStream.readLine();

    file.close();

    qDebug() << stringList;

    return 0;
}
```

#### Building (something similar)

```
g++ -fPIC -I/usr/include/qt -I/usr/include/qt/QtCore -lQt5Core main.cpp
```

#### Output

```
("string", "string2")
```